# how should I fetch my data with react-query in framework7-react?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, html-framework-7, tanstackreact-query

Im working on an framework7-react and react query for data fetching. Initialization was fine, everything works perfectly, but when I want to fetch data with react-query it has this error "No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one" and when delete the fetch part, everything became normal. what should I do? how should I fetch my data with react-query in framework7-react?

```
QueryClientProvider.js:26 Uncaught Error: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
    at useQueryClient2 (QueryClientProvider.js:26:11)
    at useBaseQuery (useBaseQuery.js:12:21)
    at useQuery (useQuery.js:7:10)
    at app (app.jsx:12:16)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
```

```
app.jsx

import React from 'react'
import { View, App } from "framework7-react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";
import {useFetchData} from '../utils/useFetchData'


export default function app() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  // const data = useFetchData();
  // console.log(data);

  // const data = useQuery(["data"], () => fetch("../utils/data.json").then(res => res.json()));
  // console.log(data);

  //I fetched in 2 ways, and both of them had the same error
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App>
    <View main url="/" />
    </App>
    <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="bottom-right" />
  </QueryClientProvider>
  )
}


useFetchdata.js

import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export function useFetchData() {
  const data = useQuery(["property"], () =>
    fetch("./data.json").then((res) => res.json())
  );

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only call the `useFetchData()` hook inside a component that is wrapped in a `QueryClientProvider`.

In your Example, you can use the hook in the `App` component or in the `View` component, because they are beneath the `QueryClientProvider` in your component tree:

```
return (
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App>
      <View main url="/" />
    </App>
    <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="bottom-right" />
  </QueryClientProvider>
)
```

but you can't use the hook in the same component that renders the `QueryClientProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

`QueryClientProvider` provides the [context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) for all queries, meaning that `QueryClientProvider` must wrap all components that use TanStack Query.

In your code you use `useQuery` in `app`, but `QueryClientProvider` does not wrap `app`, it's inside of it.

If you were to call `useQuery` (or `useFetchData`) in `App` or `View` instead, it should work.

Secondly, you should initiate `queryClient` outside of the component (in the module scope). Since React is built on multiple re-renders, the query client will be changed once `app` is re-renderd. Alternatively persist it in a `useMemo` if you want to keep it in the component.

```js
// either in module scope
const queryClient1 = new QueryClient();

export default function app() {
  // or memoize in the component
  const queryClient2 = useMemo(() => new QueryClient(), []);
```